# How to close all open Excel workbooks with VBS

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I automate a process using a .vbs file and sometimes I forget to close the excel file at night, so when the process runs the file opens as a read-only causing issues.  I'd like to just close or end all instances of open workbooks.

I thought a ".Quit" would do the trick but doesnt seems to close workbooks that are currently open. I test .quit in a macro and it does indeed close all open workbooks and the excel app in general .

Any ideas?

```
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

ExcelApp.Applicaiton.Quit

'reopen actual file as non read only

Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

ExcelApp.Visible = True

ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

ExcelFilePath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\test.xlsm"
Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)
```

Comment: Have copied and pasted the code directly? Because it says "Applicaiton.Quit" instead of "Application.Quit", and this may be the reason why quit does not work

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

try

```
Set ExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

To bind to existing excel instance.

Comment: Im using the displayAlerts but still get a msgbox on existing open file when trying to shut down asking me if I want to save or not.  Set ExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
ExcelApp.Quit

Comment: That's really weird because it says on this page that that should work?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.quit